# Can I model objects as point masses when calculating rotational inertia?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia, inertia

I have an aircraft. On it are weapons. Weapons have masses and centers of masses. The larger aircraft system has a center of mass.

I wish to calculate the cumulative rotational inertia of only the set of weapons around the center of mass of the aircraft. In general, since these objects have a volume and a mass distribution, rotational inertia for each should be calculated as

$I = \int_x \int_y \int_z \rho(x,y,z) ||\vec{r}||^2 dzdydx$

where $||\vec{r}||$ is the distance to a point in space from the axis of rotation. But I can be reasonably sure that the center of mass of the aircraft does not fall inside the volume of any weapon, so essentially I have a system of satellites rotating around some external point.

Can this be reduced to simply modeling the satellites as point masses located at their centers of mass? Clearly $I=mr^2$ is not true if rotating around a point located within the volume of an object. Does it hold for objects farther away with arbitrary density distribution?

Comment: Nope, look up the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem). The moment of inertia will be the sum of what it would be, if the object were replaced with a point mass at its CM, and the moment of inertia of the object about its own CM.

Comment: This is intuitive now that I see it. If I hold a glass of water at the end of my arm and turn my body, the water spins relative to the glass to try to maintain the same orientation. For a rigid body, there is no way for mass to slide this way, so it all must turn. In the rectangular prism example I derived I get $I = m[r^2 + \frac{l^2}{12}]$, which is clearly the inertia of the point mass added to the inertia of the rod across its center.